# google cloud function - firestore query snapshot size return undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a google function here with storage onFinalize trigger does 2 things in firestore db

1. add the element details into collection elements
2. get the size of the element collection

Why is my snapshot.size return undefined?

Console log snapshot returns the correct array result.

```
exports.elementChange = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {


    var element = {
        name: object.name,
        time: object.updated
    }


    db.collection('elements').doc(object.name).set(element)
    .then(db.collection('elements').get())
    .then((snapshot) => {

        console.log(snapshot);

        console.log("current size is "+snapshot.size);

        return console.log('element total count updated in db'); 

    })
    .catch(err => (console.log('Error when finalise element: '+ err)))

    // return console.log('finished finalise element');

})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of the problem, but you're missing a top-level `return`. Change your code to `return db.collection('elements').doc(object.name).set(element)...` to ensure your code doesn't get aborted before the write and read are finished.

Comment: I dont think it is the reason, I think it has something to do with chaining promises. If I don't chain the query under the set(element) query, it will work fine. But I can't figure out why.